# SoapUI - send login details in JSON

Tags: java, spring, soapui

I'm testing a REST sevice made in Spring using SoapUI. When I don't have a username/login, I'm able to send HTTP requests successfully. However, when I provide Spring Security like below:

```java
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Create 2 users for demo
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER")
        .and()
        .withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");

    }

    // HTTP Basic Auth for endpoints
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        //HTTP Basic authentication
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/books/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable();
    }

}
```

I keep getting error 401. I've tried hard-coding a password, setting Auth and setting paramaters in SoapUI. Can anyone advise on how to include user and password in test?

Comment: are you using http basic authentication?

Comment: Updated code, yes I'm using basic auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 2 step process.
1) Generate the token using user/pass via some online service like:- https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/

eg. for user/pwd asdf/asdf it generates:- 
Authorization: Basic YXNkZjphc2Rm

Here Authorization is your header key and Basic YXNkZjphc2Rm is header value

2) Add it to the rest endpoint like below and make your call.

[image]

Comment: So I've done that, but I get Error 401 in Representations when I make my call.

Comment: I set-up the sample project with Security config code you've provided and I am able to make a call successfully.  It is possible that you are using incorrect auth header... for user/password the encrypted token is Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==  which one you are using?

Comment: I'm also using Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==, do I need to modify the request?  Sending GET request, endpoint is http://localhost:8080 and resource is /books. No parameters.

Comment: @RandomDev Do you have a github repo i can download and try?

Comment: I'm following an online tutorial from here: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-spring-security-example/. I think it's a credential issue, as when I go through the browser and the login page I get bad credentials. I see that eclipse is generating a default hashed password, but that doesn't work either

Comment: @RandomDev: I'v downloaded the source from link in the blog and it seems to work with the header provided. Did you ensure that there are no white spaces in the header provided ?

Comment: Yeah no whitespace, to confirm I've gone to Headers, and entered Header Authorization and Value as Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==. Do I need to go to Auth and set as Basic?